# The Value of can't be null Parameter name path1

Tags: c#, forms, list, winforms, exception

```
public FormMain()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Common.listaVeicoliEliminati = new SerializableBindingList<Veicolo>();
    Common.listaVeicoliAggiunti = new SerializableBindingList<Veicolo>();
    Common.listaVeicoli = new SerializableBindingList<Veicolo>();
    Common.storico = new StoricoVendite();
    Common.storicoAggiunti = new StoricoVendite();
    Common.listaClienti = new SerializableBindingList<Cliente>();
}
```

I have problems with this code.
At the start, I want to initialize some static lists in another class, but I receive [this exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST8Qr.png).
Help me please I'm becoming mad.
PS. "Common", which is the class where there are the lists, is in another project, not in the same namespace.

Comment: This pattern is not recommended, but if you want to instantiate static lists in an other class, you should let the Common class'es static constructor do it.

Comment: Please paste the complete exception and stack trace into the question. From the looks of it `Common` has a static constructor which is passing `null` into some other method.

Comment: nothing i resolved! I switched 2 initializations at the beginning of the program!

Comment: @Jombo good to hear you found the problem. If you update the question and answer it yourself it will help others who find the same problem.

Comment: I voted to close because the question and answer is probably not helpful to anybody in its current form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public string resourcesDirectoryPath = $"{Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName}\\Risorse\\Resources\\";
private string accessDbPath = Path.Combine(resourcesDirectoryPath, "Veicoli.accdb");
```

I've just switched these 2 rows!

Comment: "just"? The order makes a big difference. Before you were using resourcesDirectoryPath before is was defined. "path1" means the first path specified in Path.Combine, which is resourcesDirectoryPath.